# re-organize array element in my case

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Suppose I have an array of string like following:

```
str_arr=["10$", "10$ I am a student","10$Good","10$ Nice weekend!"]
```

I would like to re-organize the array element value in the way that, in each element of the array , if there is(are) **white space(s) after** `10$` sign, then, **combine the** `10$` **with the following word**.

That's generating a new array like following:

```
str_arr=["10$", "10$I am a student","10$Good","10$Nice weekend!"]
```

What I tried to do is like following:

```
str_arra.map{|elem| 
     # not sure how to do here, 
     #split and check then combine again?
      if elem.size>1
         words=elem.split()
         if words[0]=='10$'
             #not sure how to do here
         end
      elsif elem.size==1
         elem
      end


 }
```

but not sure how to generate the new array ... and the code above seems verbose...

**P.S.** it is possible that there are **multiple white-spaces** after `10$`, then comes a word

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only have those cases, the following should do the trick:

```
["$ abc", "$str"].map {|v, k| v.sub(/\$ +/, '$')}
```

Here's an example: http://codepad.org/XHeo7E8B

Comment: But it is also possible that there are multiple white spaces after $ sign

Comment: yep this could lead to crashes

Comment: @Mellon I've fixed the code to work for multiple spaces - You should specify exactly what kind of data you have (you said "a white space").

Comment: what about if 10$ is the case instead of only $? what regular expression should be used then?

Comment: @Mellon Then write exactly what kind of data you have. I have provided the simplest thing that solves your problem. I will be able to write a regex only if I know exactly what kind of strings are possible in the array. What do you mean by 10$? Ten instances of $ or $ not being at the begining?

Comment: @Mellon I've seen your update, my code should already work, I've also added a link to an example in my post.

Comment: @ draevor, no, your code does not work with multiple white spaces after 10$ sign, I tried. For example if array is ["10$     3-SPACES-HERE    now"], it won't produce ["10$now"].

Comment: @Mellon You've probably copied it wrongly. If you look in the link I provided, there are multiple spaces in one of the elements (`10$    Good`). Go here and see the 3rd element of the array: http://codepad.org/XHeo7E8B

Comment: @apneadiving, how come this will cause crashes? Just out of interest

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
str_arra.map{|elem| elem.gsub(/^\$ /, "$") }
```